# OpenCV: number of pixels vs rows*columns

Tags: python, opencv, pixel

I run this code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np 

img_file='pokemon.jpg'
img=cv2.imread(img_file)  

# print total number of rows, columns and channels that are provided in the picture
print 'Image shape: ',img.shape # rows = 630, columns = 900

# now let us print the total number of pixels that the picture has 
print 'Number of pixels: ', img.size # 1701000
print 630*900 # 56700
```

Why the 2 last outputs are different ? Is not the number of columns and rows representing the number of pixels organized within the matrix of pixels ?

Comment: What `img.shape` outputs, exactly?

Comment: 630*900*3 = 1701000. Since it got three channels and each channel must contain a pixel... The only problem is it's not explained in opencv docs.

Comment: @J0HN thank you very much. So how these pixels are represented in that matrix then ?

Comment: As a 3-component vector at each mat cell, if I'm not mistaking. How the channels are actually placed depends on data type (e.g. RGB, BGR, etc.)

Comment: This should clear it up: http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/core/how_to_scan_images/how_to_scan_images.html#how-the-image-matrix-is-stored-in-the-memory

Comment: @beaker thank you so much for the link, it explains everything about this problem

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to the comment of @beaker the answer is that:

> For multichannel images the columns contain as many sub columns as the
>   number of channels. For example in case of an RGB color system:

[image]

[Documentation.](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/core/how_to_scan_images/how_to_scan_images.html#how-the-image-matrix-is-stored-in-the-memory)